# jQuery ajaxSuccess() event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is one thing I really don't like jQuery is its chaining. and all of the samples I found are using this. So is there a way to define ajaxSuccess not using chaining? I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: this.DIRECTORY_PHP,
    data: data,
    success: this.handleSuccessEvent
});
```

Comment: That should work just fine. In what way is it not working? I suspect you are losing the context `this` and assuming it's because of the ajax request.

Comment: You mean like a common success handler (global), or passing a success function into the AJAX call like you're doing above?

Comment: Thank you guys, I think the problem is not at the event handler. I just add "error" handler and it works. Sorry for raising a question without much checking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general note : "chaining" can always be broken in a succession of disctinct calls :

```
$.ajax({ ... }).done(function1).done(function2)
// can be split into :
var ajaxReq = $.ajax({ ... });
ajaxReq.done(function1);
ajaxReq.done(function2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If only `handleSuccessEvent` would have a meaning in the context (`this`), your example would work. Replace it with an existing and declared function name and ([as in documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) it will work.

```
var myFunction = function(data){ /* TODO */ };
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: this.DIRECTORY_PHP,
    data: data,
    success: myFunction
});
```

Assignment of an anonymous function to a variable is totally optional and was written to showcase the flexibility of that syntax. Feel free to follow this approach as well:

```
function myFunction(data){
/* TODO */
}

jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: this.DIRECTORY_PHP,
    data: data,
    success: myFunction
});
```